# GCP Cloud Run for Anthos - cannot increase request timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

The GCP documentation suggests that maximum timeout limit can be raised up to 24 hours for versions `0.16.0-gke.1` and later (https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/configuring/request-timeout).

As my GKE cluster and node version is `1.19.9-gke.1900`, I have the `0.20.0-gke.6` Cloud Run for Anthos version according to https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/cluster-versions and the following command.

```
kubectl get namespace knative-serving -o 'go-template={{index .metadata.labels "serving.knative.dev/release"}}'
```

However, I am still limited to 900 seconds when I want to edit and deploy a new version in Cloud Run. How can I raise the timeout limit?

[image: Cloud Run GUI]

Comment: It's a console bug I think. Try with command line, it should be fine.

Comment: Why you need the request timeout more than 900 ? I think you need to improve your code with a more asynchronous mode to speed up your job. More than 900 on request timeout is not normal I think.

Comment: Hello, just checking, neither of the 3 options listed on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout#setting), is working for you? what are the results when you are trying with the gcloud command and with the flag "--verbosity debug"? (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing via other ways, like the YAML tab. Or deploy from the CLI or using kubectl with YAML.